# How can procedures be values in MIT scheme?

Tags: stored-procedures, scheme, return-value

Conceptually I see a value as a single element. I can understand that at the lowest level of hardware the value returned is zero or one. I just see a "`value`" as returning a single unit. I see a procedure as a multiple unit. For example, a `procedure (+ x x)` to me seems like it should `return "(", ")", "+" , "x"`. In this example, the value of lambda is the procedure.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scheme is primarily a functional programming language.  Functional languages deal with *expressions<sup>1</sup>* (as opposed to *statements*);  expressions are at the core of functional languages pretty much like classes are at the core of object-oriented languages.

In Scheme, functions are expressed as [lambda expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function).  Since Scheme primarily deals with expressions, and since lambda expressions themselves are expressions, Scheme deals with functions just like any other expression.  Therefore, functions are [first-class citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) of the language.

I don't think one should feel overly concerned about how exactly all of this translates under the hood in terms of bits and bytes.  What plays as a strength in some languages (C/C++) can quickly turn against you here: imperative thinking in Scheme will only get you frustrated, and bounce you right back out to mainstream paradigms and languages.

What functional languages are really about is abstraction, [metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) (many Schemes feature powerful syntactic macros), and more abstraction.  There is this well-known quote from [Peter Deutsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_Peter_Deutsch): "Lisp ... made me aware that software could be close to executable mathematics.", I think it sums it up very well.

<sup>1</sup> In Scheme (and other dialects of LISP), [s-expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression) are used to denote expressions.  They give the language that distinctive parenthesized syntax.

Answer (score 1):

When the program is compiled the code for a procedure is generated. When you run the program the code for a procedure is stored at a given address. A procedure value will in most implementations consist of a record/struct containing the name of the procedure, the address where the procedure us stored (when you call the procedure, the cpu jumps to this address) and finally in the case of procedure created by a lambda expression a table of the free values.

Answer (score 1):

In Scheme everything is passed by value. When that said values that are not able to be stored in the actual address space of a machine word are pointers to data structures.

An internal procedure (primitive) is treated specially such that it might be just a value while a evaluated lambda expression is multi value object. That object has an address which is the "value" of the procedure. When evaluating a `lambda` form it turns into such a structure. Example:

```scm
;; a lambda form is evaluated into a closure and then 
;; that object is the value of variable x
(define x (lambda y y)) ; ==> undefined

;; x is evaluated and turns out to be a closure. Scheme 
;; evalautes rest of arguments before applying.
(x 1 2 3)               ; ==> (1 2 3)

;; same only that all the arguments also evaluates to the same closure.
(x x x x)               ; ==> (#<closure> #<closure> #<closure>)
```